# Music rating and listening statistics applications

Tags: windows, music, music-management

I'd like to know how often I listen to some tracks, manage favorite albums, artists, and most importantly specific tracks (because sometimes there are very few good tracks in an album).

Are there any applications for keeping track of music listening times, user ratings, listen counts and such for PC (usable offline)?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know for sure about tracking times, but iTunes for PC should cover the counts/ratings/favorites etc. at least.

Based on what the Mac version has (and I never use it "online") play **time** (as in the clock time you played it) does not seem to be an option, but you can view/sort by number of times you play a track, number of skips, date/time last played, date/time last skipped, rate albums and tracks separately, etc.

(You will probably need to go into "view options" and add those colums to see them - the are tracked whether or not you display them - and you'll need to use "list view" rather than the hokey graphical crap they are currently pushing...)

Answer (score 0):

I'm mainly on the Linux side, and Amarok does a good job at keeping statistics and ratings.... There's a Windows version of Amarok which might be a good alternative.